# Featured Number Pill Padding

Tags: bug, design

The pill with the count in it needs some padding on the top.

**Selected:**
[image]

**Hover:**
[image]

I've confirmed this issue on Safari 7.0.1, Chrome 33.0, Firefox 27.0.1.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this issue is prevalent with basically every pill on the site.

Comment: Huh. Did not know "pill" was the name for those things. Anyways, I always assumed this UX was intentional, and it never bothered me. `</twoCents>`